# MySQL select uniques from two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different tables, and I want to get the uniques as if they where a single table. The table structures are the same. I have tried `UNION`, `UNION DISTINCT`, `SELECT DISTINCT with a UNION`, and all kinds of things. But I am still getting duplicates and stuff.

Is there anyways to get the unique email address along with other data

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_address, first_name, last_name,
    street_address, city, postal_code, province, created_date
FROM entries
WHERE subscribe='1'
```

That gets it from one table.

Note, if I just wanted the email address, UNION works. But when I add the other data it doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: Have you tried a `JOIN`?

Comment: Can you do a DISTINCT join? Like I want to get everything from both tables. Then remove all duplicate emails. Ignoring the rest of the data, and including the where clause.

Comment: `select distinct ...` applies to the entire row - all fields, not just the first field in the select statement. e.g. you're telling mysql to make sure the ROW is distinct, not the email_address field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT email_address, first_name, last_name,
    street_address, city, postal_code, province, created_date
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM entries WHERE subscribe='1'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM entries2 WHERE subscribe='1') AS tmp
GROUP BY email_address
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    (SELECT /*Fields*/ FROM entries e1)
    UNION
    (SELECT /*same Fields*/ FROM entries2 e2)
    WHERE subscribe=1
    GROUP BY email_address
```